# Navbar and path problems

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I am making a web page and having trouble with navbar. One of my navbar items is "patient List" and the path is "/patientlist". The problem is that I set individual patient path to "/patient" instead of "/patientlist/patient" which causes the problem that the "patient List" navbar item couldn't recognize that and the "patient List" icon is not highlighted. How can I add exception to my code to make the path "/patient" recognize as "/patientlist/patient" ?

```
export default function NavBar() {
  const { data: userSessionData } = useSession();
  const currPath = usePathname();
  const data = useMemo(() => getNavData(userSessionData), [userSessionData]);
  const isActive = (path) => {
    const checkPath = path.startsWith("#");
    const itempath = path === "/" ? "/" : `${path}`;
    if (itempath === "/") {
      return !checkPath && currPath === itempath;
    } else {
      return (
        (!checkPath && currPath === itempath) ||
        (!checkPath && currPath.includes(itempath))
      );
    }
  };
```